# when we use json data type in database?

Tags: mysql, json, database, postgresql

I want to ask.. 
 1. When do we use JSON data type in a database? 
 2. What about performance if the data size is big? 
Example: 
I have user credential table with the following columns:

1. name
2. email
3. password
4. status
5. phone

and I want to add adittional data like address, sex, photo, zip code

What is the best solution?

1. Just add the columns into the existing table user
2. Create a new table
3. Create a new json data type

I am sorry if the question is basic.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. just adding the column into existing table user _As these items appear to be 1 to 1 with the concept of a User_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To use json data type in table assume that data is stored in json format by using bytea/blob we can save json in postgresql database.
2. Its better to Alter table and Add columns to existing table.
3. Performance of Database directly related to Memory or Space available in Computer/Server (so it doesn't matter if data is big)